# Pagging in Kendo Grid MVC cause to HttpContext.Current.Session["Token"] bcame null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

im using kendo grid MVC in ASP.net MVC and load data with Server side pagging and the way i Use for Data source is

```
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
                  .Model(model =>
                  {
                      model.Id(m => m.ID);

                  })
                  .Read(read => read.Action("Persons_Read", "Person").Data("PersonPage.GetFilterData"))

              )
```

also i have read method to load data for grid like this one:

```
 public ActionResult Persons_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string name, string code, string groups, bool allData = false)
    {
        var personMng=new PersonManager();
        var total = 0;
        var result = personMng.GetlstAllPersons(request.Page,out total);
         var resultData=  result.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        resultData.Total = total;
        return Json(resultData);}
```

for the first time i load page my session:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["Token"];
```

has value but for the time i choice page 2 in kendo grid the session get null value. so how can i keep the value to session in page 2 and other pages? also after i click page 2 then i couldnt use any other sessions in other pages of my Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found An Answer It's because in My Read Method I change data in Bin Folder of Project so the website get restart.
i changed the place of file other than bin folder so it works fine.